# When should I use E.altW as opposed to E.orElse?

Tags: fp-ts

I'm trying to understand the diference between E.altW and E.orElse, but both seem to do the same. For example, I can construct a Semigroup that concatenates parsing functions using either of them:

```
import * as E from 'fp-ts/Either';
import * as A from 'fp-ts/Array';
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/function';
import * as S from 'fp-ts/Semigroup';

const parseString = (u: unknown): E.Either<string, string> =>
  typeof u === 'string' ? E.right(u) : E.left('not a string');

const parseNumber = (u: unknown): E.Either<string, number> =>
  typeof u === 'number' ? E.right(u) : E.left('not a number');

const ParseSemigroup: S.Semigroup<
  (u: unknown) => E.Either<string, string | number>
> = {
  concat(a, b) {
    return (input) =>
      pipe(
        a(input),
        E.altW(() => b(input))
      );
  },
};

const ParseSemigroup2: S.Semigroup<
  (u: unknown) => E.Either<string, number | string>
> = {
  concat(a, b) {
    return (input) =>
      pipe(
        a(input),
        E.orElse(() => b(input))
      );
  },
};

const manyParsers = S.concatAll(ParseSemigroup)(parseNumber)([parseString]);
console.log(manyParsers('99'));

const manyParsers2 = S.concatAll(ParseSemigroup2)(parseNumber)([parseString]);
console.log(manyParsers('99'));
```

And the result is exactly the same, as you can see.
When should I use one over the other? or what are the specific usecases of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, one thing to note is that `altW` is slightly different from `alt` and likewise for `onElseW` and `onElse`. The `W` suffix stands for ‘widen’ and it means you can do things like this:

```ts
const result: Either<never, string | number> = pipe(
  E.right(''),
  E.altW(() => E.right(0))
)
```

where the resulting `Either` has a union type inside of it. You can read more about this on the [fp-ts FAQ](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/guides/code-conventions.html#what-a-w-suffix-means-eg-chainw-or-chaineitherkw).

---

Here’s the types of `alt` and `onElse` and their `W` counterparts:

```ts
declare const     alt: <E , A    >(that:   ()      => Either<E , A>) =>        (fa: Either<E , A>) => Either<E , A    >
declare const  orElse: <E1, A, E2>(onLeft: (e: E1) => Either<E2, A>) =>        (ma: Either<E1, A>) => Either<E2, A    >
declare const    altW: <E2, B    >(that:   ()      => Either<E2, B>) => <E1, A>(fa: Either<E1, A>) => Either<E2, B | A>
declare const orElseW: <E1, E2, B>(onLeft: (e: E1) => Either<E2, B>) => <    A>(ma: Either<E1, A>) => Either<E2, B | A>
```

Because TypeScript types can look pretty messy, here’s the same thing but with a Haskell-like syntax:

```hs
alt     :: (() -> Either e  a) -> Either e  a -> Either e  a
orElse  :: (e1 -> Either e2 a) -> Either e1 a -> Either e2 a
altW    :: (() -> Either e2 b) -> Either e1 a -> Either e2 (b | a)
orElseW :: (e1 -> Either e2 b) -> Either e1 a -> Either e2 (b | a)
```

As you can hopefully see, the main difference between `alt` and `orElse` is that the function passed into `orElse` takes in the error `E1`. In your case where the function passed to `onElse` ignores/does not use the error, `alt` and `onElse` are equivalent. In this case, `alt` is the more appropriate function to use here.

If you want to return a new `Either` with a different error and/or success type, then you should use `altW`/`orElseW`.

So, in summary:

- Do you need to use the error from the first either to return the second either?

  - Yes: Use `orElse`/`orElseW`
  - No: Use `alt`/`altW`
- Does the second either have different types to the first either?

  - Yes: Use `orElseW`/`altW`
  - No: Use `orElse`/`alt`

---

### Side note: Alternative

You may have noticed that there’s another difference between `alt` and `orElse`: in `orElse`, the either returned by the function can have a different error type `E2`.

This is because the `alt` function comes from the [`Alt`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Alt.ts.html) typeclass:

```ts
interface Alt<F> extends Functor<F> {
  readonly alt: <A>(fa: HKT<F, A>, that: LazyArg<HKT<F, A>>) => HKT<F, A>
}
```

In the case of `Either`, you can think of `HKT<F, A>` like `Either<E, A>`, so the `E` has to be the same both in `fa` and `that`.